# Генерация диапазона времени с шагом N

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Мне нужно сгенерировать временную суточную таблицу времени с шагом в 5 минут, т.е. должно получится:

```
time |
--------
00.00
00.05
00.10
...
23.45
23.50
23.55
```

Как подобное можно сделать средствами MySQL?

Comment: Посмотрите [**тут**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132024/how-to-populate-a-table-with-a-range-of-dates) возможно это то, что вам нужно :)

Comment: Спасибо! Но хранимые процедуры не подходят (ограничения заказчика). Я думал в MySQL есть какие нибудь функции но похоже что нет. Даже цикл нельзя использовать вне контекста хранимых процедур (

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем мне ничего не подошло, поэтому создал отдельную таблицу и заполнил её нужными данными